# SQL Reporting Services IIf statement

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a report that should execute a different equation depending on the status of the boolean field CLIPPING_FLAG.  However, no matter the state of this field, the second equation seems to always be selected.  Here is my expression.

=IIf(Fields!CLIPPING_FLAG.Value = False, (Fields!DRY_M2.Value/Fields!FLITCH_COUNT.Value),
(Fields!CLIP_M2.Value/Fields!BUNDLE_COUNT.Value))

Comment: Change your iif false value to a 0.. like this =IIf(Fields!CLIPPING_FLAG.Value = 0,.....

Comment: Thanks Harry.  I have tried this again and it does the same thing.  I am at a loss as I have created another cell that just shows the value of clipping_flag and this shows correctly each line.

Comment: If someone can explain why the If statement does not seem to work I would greatly appreciate it.  I ended up adding a Code section to my report this morning to get it to work.     Public Function Average(ByVal ClipFlag As Boolean, ByVal ClipM2 As Double, ByVal BundleCount As Integer, ByVal DryM2 As Double, ByVal FlitchCount As Integer) As Double
If ClipFlag = False
 Return DryM2/FlitchCount
Else
 Return ClipM2/BundleCount
End If
End Function

Comment: Then I just called Code.Average as passed values.

Comment: As a test, try removing the `= False` and then reversing the order of the next two expressions. I suspect, for whatever reason, SSRS is not treating the Field as a boolean, it may even be interpreted as a string. If this still does not work, try comparing with `"False"`. Hard to tell without seeing it so these are just some things to help investigate

Comment: I would try using the CBool to explicitly convert the boolean value `=IIF(CBool(Fields!CLIPPING_FLAG.Value) = False, ...`